# Using spring boot thymeleaf : Display image and other information in a table at front end

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-upload, thymeleaf

I have created advertisement table and inserted details and image of advertisement in the file system and other information in database. The name of image is the id of the each entry. Now I have to display all of the information in a table using thymeleaf but I am not able to do that. Please check the code below::--

1. Model class:

```
    private String advertisementDesc;
    
    @Column(name = "advertisement_no")
    private String advertisementNo;
    
    @Column(name = "publish_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date publishDate;
        
    @Column(name = "close_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date closeDate;
        
    @Column(name = "apply_multiple_post")
    private Boolean applyMultiplePost;
    
    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean isActive;
    
    @Column(name = "action_by")
    private long actionBy;
    
    @Column(name = "action_date")
    private Date actionDate;
    
    @Column(name = "action_by_ip", length = 19)
    private String actionByIp;
```

2. Repository Interface:

```
@Repository
public interface AdvertisementRepository extends JpaRepository (Advertisement, Integer) {
    
}
```

3. Interface Storage Service:

```
public interface AdvertisementStorageService {
    
    void init();

    void store(MultipartFile file, Integer id);

    Stream<Path> loadAll();

    Path load(String filename);

    Resource loadAsResource(String filename);

    void deleteAll();
    
    Page < Advertisement > findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize);
    
}
```

4. Storage service implementation (loadAll method)

```
    @Override
    public Stream<Path> loadAll() {
        try {
            return Files.walk(this.rootLocation, 1)
                    .filter(path -> !path.equals(this.rootLocation))
                    .map(path -> this.rootLocation.relativize(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new StorageException("Failed to read stored files", e);
        }

    }
```

5. In Controller trying to use Index method to generate list to display at thymeleaf template:

```
    @GetMapping("index/page/{pageNo}")
    public String findPaginated(@PathVariable(value = "pageNo") int pageNo, Model model) {
        int pageSize = 2;

        Page<Advertisement> page = advertisementStorageService.findPaginated(pageNo, pageSize);
        List<Advertisement> listAdvt = page.getContent();

        model.addAttribute("currentPage", pageNo);
        model.addAttribute("totalPages", page.getTotalPages());
        model.addAttribute("totalItems", page.getTotalElements());
        model.addAttribute("listAdvt", listAdvt);
        
        return "advertisement/index-advertisement";
    }

    @GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> serveFile(@PathVariable String filename) {

        Resource file = advertisementStorageService.loadAsResource(filename);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(file);
    }
 @GetMapping("index")       // This is to show index page
            public String showAdvertisementIndex(Model model) {
             
             model.addAttribute("files", advertisementStorageService
                     .loadAll()
                     .map(path -> MvcUriComponentsBuilder.fromMethodName(AdvertisementController.class,
                        "serveFile", path.getFileName().toString()).build().toUri().toString())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
             Iterable<Advertisement> data = advertisementRepository.findAll();
             
             model.addAttribute("advertisements", advertisementRepository.findAll());
             return findPaginated(1, model);  
             
//                  return "advertisement/index-advertisement";
        }
```

6. Thymeleaf Index template

   ```
                                    <tr th:each="advertisement,iterator : ${advertisements}">
                                        <td th:text="${iterator.count}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${advertisement.id}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${advertisement.advertisementDesc}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${advertisement.advertisementNo}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${advertisement.publishDate}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${advertisement.closeDate}"></td>
                                        <!--                                            <td th:text="${advertisement.advertisementFile}"></td> -->
                                        <td th:text="${advertisement.applyMultiplePost}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${advertisement.isActive}"></td>
                                        <td><a
                                            th:href="@{/advertisement/edit/{id}(id=${advertisement.id})}"
                                            class="btn btn-success"> <i
                                                class="fas fa-user-edit ml-2"></i></a></td>
                                        <td><a
                                            th:href="@{/advertisement/delete/{id}(id=${advertisement.id})}"
                                            class="btn btn-success"> <i
                                                class="fas fa-user-times ml-2"></i></a></td>
                                        <td>document</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td th:text="${localDateTime}"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr th:each="file: ${files}">
                                        <td><a th:href="${file}" /> <img
                                            th:src="@{/img/pdf.png}" style="width: 50px; height: 60px;">

                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                    </tr>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `advertisements` list to the model attributes.

On the other hand, for download files, you can attach the `InputStream` in the response.

```java
@GetMapping("/files/{filename:.+}")
public void serveFile(@PathVariable String filename, HttpServletResponse response) {

     // Load the inputStream
     // InputStream = ...


     // Attach in the response
     String contentType = new ConfigurableMimeFileTypeMap().getContentType(fileName);
     res.setContentType(contentType);
     res.addHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment;filename=\"%s\"", fileName));

     ByteStreams.copy(inputStream, res.getOutputStream());
}
```

Comment: Yes I have added list in
'''
model.addAttribute("advertisement", advertisementRepository.findAll());
'''
But it does not give the filepath and file name. for which I have made a seperate list in '''model.addAttribute("files", advertisementStorageService..........'''
You can see the showAdvertisementIndex() method in controller.

Comment: Sorry I have just corrected advertisement to advertisements but problem is I have two lists to show. I want one list which will be iterated on thymeleaf html page.

Comment: You can iterate a single list. So in "td" for files you need to provide a link to download the file from the controller as explained in the last example.